Angualr cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport not working properly
I am trying to implement an infinite scroll using cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport where I load images lazily as the viewport reaches the bottom of the page into a grid.

Problem is that it only renders 3 rows and when I reach the bottom although new images are retrieved but it does not show in the browser.
Here is the html code where I use mat-grid-list for each row:
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport appendOnly [itemSize]="itemSize" class="grid-viewport" (scrolledIndexChange)="viewPortChange($event)">
    <mat-grid-list *cdkVirtualFor="let item of items" [cols]="gridColumns" gutterSize="10px" class="grid-list">
        @for(it of item; track it.description){
            <mat-grid-tile   class="grid-item">
                <img [src]="it.imageUrl" alt="Item image" class="grid-img">
            </mat-grid-tile>
        }
    </mat-grid-list>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>

Following is the component typescript code where viewPortChange method is called when bottom of the page is reached but the new images are not shown in the browser. I store the data as a nested array where the inner arrays contain 4 images each:

items : any[][] =  []; 
  loadedElementsCount: number = 0;
  batchSize: number = 12;
  itemSize: number = 200;
  gridColumns: number = 4;
  nbLoadRows = 3;

  constructor() {}


  ngOnInit() {
    this.calculateGridSettings();
    this.loadMoreItems();
  }

loadMoreItems() {
    const newItems = Array.from({ length: this.batchSize }, (_, i) => this.createItem(i + this.items.length*this.gridColumns));
    
    for(let i = 0; i < this.batchSize; i+=this.gridColumns){
      this.items.push(newItems.slice(i,i+this.gridColumns));
    }
    //this.items = [...this.items, ...newItems];
    this.loadedElementsCount += this.batchSize;
    console.log("loaded number");
    console.log(this.loadedElementsCount);
    //console.log(newItems);
    console.log(this.items);
  }

  viewPortChange(event: any){
    console.log("evemtdtsr number");
    console.log(event)
    if((event+1)*this.gridColumns >= this.loadedElementsCount){ //*this.gridColumns
      this.loadMoreItems();
    }
  }
  createItem(index: number) {
    return {
      imageUrl: `https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=${index}`,
      description: `Item ${index}`
    };
  }

Anyone has an idea why this happens?
